# How can we execute a terminal-command for all the subfolders, at once

Tags: permissions, root, chmod, chown

I need to change ownership of my Downloads folder from root to my username. Using 'chown' and '*' wildcard I could get around with each folder and it's files but that's tedious. Anything I could do here to ease my job?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by you saying that `chown -R user:group Downloads` is tedious. How come?

Comment: Since there are folders within folders with folders... and files too. I have to cd back to each folder and repeat the process.

Comment: right, that's what the command above does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown):

> ```
>    -R, --recursive
>           operate on files and directories recursively
> ```

So, you should use:

```
chown -R username Downloads
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't knew of the -recursive flag. Every time there's something new to learn in ubuntu, isn't there?

Comment: @PythonStudent All of us we are **students** on this site :)